# Is there a way to send a blog post to my Google sites from an email?

Tags: blogger, google-classic-sites

I use WordPress for my personal blog and website and I would like to use all Google products. I really like posting to my WordPress blog via email. is there a way to do this with Google sites?

Thank you all for your comments, now that I have found the Google Blogger option I think their support sites have all the information I need.
Special thanks to Ale

Comment: Blogger is Google's blogging platform. Shouldn't you be asking about that?

Comment: (And for Blogger, [the answer is yes](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/154172).)

Comment: By the other hand, there are two version of Google Sites. Is this question about the classic or the new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sites does not have the option to send a post via email, but Blogger does. So I would have to create a new page on the google site which holds or links to the Blogger blog. and also include linked pages on Blogger to the website.

a bit complicated but it is a good Google only solution.